# Python - Max and Min sorting

Tags: python

EDIT: testing out the maxxx function with new changes. output still the print statement in 2nd line. (no indentation errors thrown)
I need to sort this list using custom function (I cannot use built in functions).

### When I run, it only outputs the second print statement. How can I make it work?

```
    nums = [0, 3.14159, 5, 1, 9, 2.71828, -1]
    print(nums)
    def maxxx():
        maxy = nums[0]
        for num in nums:
            if nums[i+1] > maxy:
                print("The maximum number in the list is:", maxy)
                return maxy
        maxxx()
    def minnn():
        miny = nums[1]
        while i in range (nums):
            if nums[i+1] < miny:
                return miny
            print ("The minimm number in the list is:", miny)
        minnn()
```

Comment: Because your `print` is after the `return` (same indent block). It would never get executed.

Comment: I tried swapping return and print statement for function def maxxx(). It still is the same.

Comment: So basically the output in shell "[0,3.14159,5,1,9,2.71828, -1]"

Comment: Do `maxy = nums[0]` and use `for` instead of `while`. Also use the elements directly instead of iterating by index number. e.g. `for num in nums:`

Comment: ok so i tried that, i have kep thte def minnn() unchanged, i'm trying out changes in def maxxx(), i now used a for statement and set maxy = nums[0], still same output as before. I'm wondering if if nums is actually in fact treated as a list rather than string, because the output is exactly the way i initialized it with brackets. and also wondering if i need to do maxxx(nums)

Comment: Kindly fix your indentation and update the code with the latest one. (edit the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a decent number of issues.  Basically, your return was in the wrong spot, meaning it would only check the first element.  I'd recommend just reading through the following and comparing it with your own code.

```
nums = [0, 3.14159, 5, 1, 9, 2.71828, -1]
def maxxx():
   maxy = nums[0]
   for num in nums:
      if num > maxy:
         maxy = num
   print("The maximum number in the list is:", maxy)
   return maxy
def minnn():
   miny = nums[0]
   for num in nums:
      if num < miny:
         miny = num
   print ("The minimm number in the list is:", miny)
   return miny

print(nums)
maxxx()
minnn()
```

Comment: this works!! thank you so much! i took note of indentation too: so far i kept correcting if it showed indentation error. now i can align properly for future coding. we just learned functions in class yesterday btw i'll practice more

Comment: And I just updated my response with correct indentation.

Comment: ok sure, just check marked it as answer, took me a while to find that, now i know. (new to stack overflow too).